# meaning of const int* const fun(const int* const& p) const;

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

```
const int* const fun(const int* const& p) const;
```

I'm trying to figure out about the input parameter at this given function prototype. I'm debating between these two, not sure which one is correct.

1. The input is a const reference which refers to a const int pointer. Hence the reference is constant, and the pointer is constant, but the value it points to can be changed.
2. The input is a const reference to a const int pointer which points to a constant integer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointer to reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37722448/pointer-to-reference)

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a reference to a constant pointer to a constant integer.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is a reference to a const pointer to a const `int`.

Reference aren't `const` by themselves - "const references" are just references to const objects. Hence, "const reference to pointer to const int" would be understood to mean the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

> The input is a const reference which refers to a const int pointer. Hence the reference is constant, and the pointer is constant, but the value it points to can be changed.

Not true. The argument `p` cannot be changed to point to a different object. The value of the object that `p` points to cannot be changed either.

> The input is a const reference to a const int pointer which points to a constant integer.

Sort of.

`p` is a reference to a const pointer which points to a const integer.

Answer (score 0):

The input is a reference on a const pointer which point to the const integer.

```
const int* const& p
```

The first const indicates that the int object itself is constant and can't be changed. The second const indicated that the pointer on that int can't be changed. Then you see that it's a reference. You can add one more const for the reference and it will compile. Like that:

```
const int* const& const p
```

Comment: References can't be const-specified, because mutable references don't exist.

Comment: @Quentin yes, they don't exist, but this also compiles, at least on msvc :) Though that's a nonsense

Answer (score 0):

> `const int* const& P`

P is a reference(not constant reference, as reference is always constant) to a constant pointer, which is pointing to constant integer.

The first constant is for integer & second one is for pointer(not reference). There is no point of passing a reference of constant pointer as it is constant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think the below code snippet will answer your question if you could just run it.

I have explained how the argument `const int* const& p` is created, referenced and passed.

This is a simple tricky function that just returns the similar data type as the one being passed into except that the argument is referenced. Added twist is the const function but in the below case it will mean no difference.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Complex{
    public:
        const int* const fun(const int* const& p) const;

};

const int* const Complex::fun(const int* const& p) const{
    return p;
}


int main(){

    int i =10;
    const int* j = &i;
    const int* const& p = j;

    cout << "i = " << i << " is stored at address " << &i << endl;
    cout << "j is pointing to i's address " << j << " at j's own address " << &j << endl;
    cout << "p is referencing j's address at " << &p << " and also holds the value same as j which is i's address " << p << endl;
    cout << "j can get the show in i with expression *j which will output " << *j <<endl;
    cout << "similary p can show the value in i with express *p which will output " << *p <<endl;

    Complex c;
    cout << c.fun(p) << " has value " << *c.fun(p);
    return 0;
}
```