# Pointer to reference

Tags: c++

I was reading, and I saw the following code:

```
template <>
inline bool is_empty(const char* const& x)
{
    return x==0 || *x==0;
}
```

What does `const char* const& x` mean?

I tried the following code to understand it:

```
void f(const char* const& x) 
{
    // whatever
}

void main()
{
    char a = 'z';
    char &j = a;
    f(a);//error
    f(*a);//error
    f(&a);//fine
    f(j);//error
    f(&j);//fine     
    f('z');//error
}
```

It works only for `f(&a)` and `f(&j)`.

What does `const char* const& x` actually mean?

Comment: It's like `f(const T&)`, where `T = const char*`.

Comment: `const` qualifies a type such that modifying the object becomes ill-formed. The error messages that you get in each case should explain what's going on.

Comment: Note that it is not a pointer to reference as the title says (no such thing exists), but a reference to a pointer.

Comment: I was going to say that passing by reference seems useless, but it looks like it's a template specialization where the template accepts references in the general case.

Comment: Rule of thumb: read type declarations right to left. So "const char* const& x" means "x is a reference (&) to a constant (second const) pointer (*) to a char which is constant (first const)". -- This, BTW, is why I prefer the equivalent "char const * const & x" (x is a reference to a constant pointer to a constant char). Or typedefs. typedefs are your friend.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A pointer reference is exactly what it says, a reference to a pointer.

Consider what we know about references. A reference in C++ is a variable that refers to an existing variable elsewhere:

```
int x = 1;
int &y = x;    // <-- y refers to x. Any changes to y will update x as well, and vice versa.
```

Also consider what we know about pointers. A pointer points to another object in memory:

```
int *m = new int(5);   // Pointer to an allocated integer in memory.
int *n = m;            // Pointer to the same memory.
```

So in your case what you actually have is a reference to a pointer!

```
int *m = new int(5);   // Pointer to an allocated integer in memory.
int *ptr = m;          // Pointer to m.
int *&ptrRef = ptr;    // Reference to ptr.
```

In the example above, changing ptrRef would update the *pointer*, but not the value.

Here's a bit more of a complete example:

```
int *myPtr = new int(5);   // myPtr points to an integer.

...

void ChangePointer(int *&ptr)
{
    delete ptr;
    ptr = new int(6);
}

...

std::cout << *myPtr << std::endl;  // <-- Output "5"
ChangePointer(myPtr);
std::cout << *myPtr << std::endl;  // <-- Output "6"
```

In the example above, we pass `myPtr` to the `ChangePointer` by reference so that it can be modified by the function. If we did not pass by reference, any changes made inside the function would be lost.

In your case, you're passing a reference to a const pointer. This is approximately equivalent to:

```
DoStuff(const Object &myObject);
```

In your case, you're passing a pointer, rather than an object though.

It seems a bit redundant to pass a const pointer by reference though. The pointer cannot be changed (it is const), and there is no benefit to passing pointers by reference (pass by reference is no more efficient than pass by value for small objects like pointers and integers). I wouldn't want to guess as to why it was done in your case.

Comment: Could you fix line 2 in the 1st code-section?  You use "a" in stead of "x". That's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 33):

[cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) is an useful online tool to help beginners get used to complicated declarations.

Inserting `const char* const& i` returns:

> declare i as reference to const pointer to const char

The meaning of the declaration should be obvious now.

Comment: I think its  "constant reference to constant pointer of char type"

Comment: @sagar: No, there is no such thing as a constant reference. By nature references are themselves constant (cannot be reseated) so adding "constant" before it is a pleonasm.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes you are write. I misinterpreted the declaration. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen yes there is. Constant reference is the same thing as reference to constant. Although, since it's the same thing, sagar's "correction" is a bit superfluous. Constant (or const) reference is used more in parctice (in my experience) than reference to const, although the latter is more descriptive and therefore better in this context, where clarity is of importance.

Comment: @sagar ... although, prepending constant to "reference to const" is indeed redundant and it's indeed a pointer to const char, so I don't mean to say that the misinterpreted declaration is correct.

Comment: cdecl doesn't support C++ notations like references and pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 10):

Let's take this apart:

- the trailing `&` means this is a *reference* to whatever the type is.
- `const char` is the type that's being pointed to
- `* const` means the pointer is constant

So, this is a reference to a const pointer to a const char. You can't change the `char` that it points to (unless you cast away the `constness`), and you can't change the pointer (i.e. make it point to something else). The pointer is passed by reference, so that no copying occurs.

Comment: Which means that what?

Comment: Simple and clear. And the use of the 'const &' pattern makes `f("hello");` also acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers largely cover the semantics of references to pointers.

But what if you were in doubt: is it a *reference to pointer* or *pointer to reference*? It can be confusing! However, **C++ does not allow pointer to references!**

Pointers store the address of *objects* and references are **not** objects, so there cannot be any pointer to reference.

Answer (score 0):

It should translate to "A reference to a constant pointer to constant character". 
Which means the referenced pointer can't be assigned a new target address (to point to) and the string it references must not be modified.

edited after comment. Consequences should remain the same though.

Comment: it's not a constant ref, it's a reference to a const pointer.

Comment: Correct, sorry. Got confused about right-to-left const association near the end.

Comment: @MarcusMüller constant reference is the same thing as reference to constant. Even the standard talks about "const reference", even though reference to const might be a better description.