# EspHome custom component

Tags: c++, arduino, esphome

i have a probleme with custom code in esphome..
There is the error :

```
src/screen.h:23:59: error: cannot convert 'MyCustomComponent::MyCustomComponent(esphome::template_::TemplateNumber*&, esphome::template_::TemplateNumber*&, esphome::template_::TemplateNumber*&, esphome::homeassistant::HomeassistantTextSensor*&)::<lambda(String)>' to 'std::function<void(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>)>'
   23 |                                           { str = str_n; });
      |                                                           ^
```

and the code :

```
  MyCustomComponent(esphome::template_::TemplateNumber *&_led_r,esphome::template_::TemplateNumber *&_led_g,esphome::template_::TemplateNumber *&_led_b,esphome::homeassistant::HomeassistantTextSensor *&_str)
  {
    _led_r->add_on_state_callback([this](float led_r_n)
                                      { led_r = led_r_n; });
    _led_g->add_on_state_callback([this](float led_g_n)
                                      { led_g = led_g_n; });                                      
    _led_b->add_on_state_callback([this](float led_b_n)
                                      { led_b = led_b_n; });
    _str->add_on_state_callback([this](String str_n)
                                          { str = str_n; });                                      
  }
```

I'm really lost..

thank you in advance

EDIT :
here is my code :
here is my code, in case I specify that I run this on a HomeAssistant instance with EspHome in version 2022.8.3

```
#include "esphome.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include "rgb_lcd.h"
 
class MyCustomComponent : public Component, public CustomAPIDevice {
 
 public:
  rgb_lcd lcd;
  bool enable = false;
  int led_r = 0;
  int led_g = 0;
  int led_b = 0;
  String str = "ff";
  MyCustomComponent(esphome::template_::TemplateNumber *&_led_r,esphome::template_::TemplateNumber *&_led_g,esphome::template_::TemplateNumber *&_led_b,esphome::homeassistant::HomeassistantTextSensor *&_str)
  {
    _led_r->add_on_state_callback([this](float led_r_n)
                                      { led_r = led_r_n; });
    _led_g->add_on_state_callback([this](float led_g_n)
                                      { led_g = led_g_n; });                                      
    _led_b->add_on_state_callback([this](float led_b_n)
                                      { led_b = led_b_n; });
    _str->add_on_state_callback([this](String str_n)
                                          { str = str_n; });                                      


  }
  void setup() override {
    lcd.begin(16, 2);
  }
  
    void loop() override
  {
       lcd.setRGB(led_r,led_g,led_b);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but by are you taking the pointers by reference? You are not changing what they point at.

Comment: I must admit that I'm coding a little blind for this project, I don't know how to use c+, when you say pointer by reference, what do you mean?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37722942/4902099) for pointer by reference. Your custom class is expecting a `* &_led_r`, question will be how do you defined the `_led_r` in your main function. and how do you instantiate your custom class?

Comment: but why if i remove all part of str value it works ?

Comment: What does [the automation YAML file](https://esphome.io/guides/automations.html#automation) look like?

Comment: i don't have automation on this, just esphome config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown [here](https://esphome.io/api/classesphome_1_1text__sensor_1_1_text_sensor.html)

```
void esphome::text_sensor::TextSensor::add_on_state_callback(std::function< void(std::string)>callback)
```

You should use std::string instead of String (Arduino string), those are incompatible.
I'm not sure what you're going to do with `String str = "ff";` but In case you still want to use Arduino String, you should be able to use like

```
_str->add_on_state_callback([this](std::string str_n)
                                      { str = String(str_n); });
```